# Checkout specific release code for chromium from GoogleSource repository

Tags: chromium

I am wondering, how to Checkout specific release code for chromium, after they move their project to new [repository](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code).

See this release Tags.
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+refs

I am wondering how i could get the code for specific tag for example 55.0.2883.46
when i use

```
sudo git checkout -b  "tags/55.0.2883.46" ;
gclient sync --jobs 16;
```

Is not work as i expect

Answer (score 0):

Finally, The solution is writing this line only

```
sudo git checkout  "tags/55.0.2883.46"  -b "s55.0.2883.46" ;
```

s55.0.2883.46 : the new local branch name